# How to Resize (to bigger) an image using slimbox2

Tags: slimbox

I would like to resize an image using image gallery with slimbox2.

My original images are 400 px of width but i would like to show them with 600 px of width at least.

I already tried to explore the css files or the js files but until now i haven't figured out how to do it so i would appreciate any help on this matter.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible. I did not design Slimbox 2 to allow resizing images. It's a very simple implementation.